# "It" as a pronoun for event

Tags: grammar, word-usage, semantic-roles

By definition, the word "it" is used in placed of a thing or situation mentioned beforehand. My questions is - can "it" serve as the pronoun for an event such as birthday party, award ceremony or sport match?

e.g. 1) The end of semester award ceremony is coming up, I wonder what awards I will receive at it (the ceremony).

2) There will be a meeting next week, and during it we will discuss the topic of saving resources.

3) So you did go to the party. Did anything strange happen at it?

Are the above sentences correct english? If not how can I improve them?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! 'It' can basically be used for any *thing*, *situation*, *event* or *concept* - anything which is not covered by 'I', 'you', 'we', 'she' or 'he'. ('They' can be either people or things/situations/events/concepts.)